# Calling Procedure in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I want to call a Procedure to populate drop down in a form.  Right now I  am using the code like this:

```
 <td class="style4">Choose Category:&nbsp;<font color="red">*</font></td>
 <td class="style3">
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="cat1"
                                                        DataTextField="catname" DataValueField="catname">
     </asp:DropDownList>
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="cat1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:billingdatabase%>" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT [catname] FROM [Category]">
     </asp:SqlDataSource>
 </td>
```

**The Procedure:**

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spshowproducts]
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT catname FROM Category 
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question fully - some more details would be appreciated.

If your User Defined Function is a Stored Procedure you should be able to use that as the basis for the data. Bind your `DropDownList` to an `SqlDataSource`, and set the source for the `SqlDataSource` as the name of the Stored Procedure rather than specifying raw SQL.

Comment: ok now I have a procedure name showproducts but don't know how to use it to populate the dropdown.

Comment: OK when you configure your SQLDataSource, select 'Specify a custom SQL Statement or stored procedure', then at the bottom of the next window you can select 'Stored procedure:' and choose one from the dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <td class="style4">Choose Category:&nbsp;<font color="red">*</font></td>
                                                <td class="style3">
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="cat1"
                                                        DataTextField="catname" DataValueField="catname">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="cat1" runat="server"
                                                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:billingdatabase%>"
                                                        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"
                                                        SelectCommand="EXEC [dbo].[spshowproducts]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                                    </td>
```